# Does the `cross_val_score` do cross validation on the sampled dataset or the original?

Tags: scikit-learn

From this example taken from https://machinelearningmastery.com/smote-oversampling-for-imbalanced-classification/

```py
# define pipeline

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
over = SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.1, k_neighbors=k)
under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.5)
steps = [('over', over), ('under', under), ('model', model)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)

# evaluate pipeline
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, X, y, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
score = mean(scores)
```

We see that a pipeline including over and undersampling is applied to `X`. My question is, is the scoring (which is computing `roc_auc`) performed on the original (X, y) dataset? Or on the sampled dataset? What I mean is, is the score from:

```
score(model(X), y)
```

or is it from:

```
score(model(undersample(oversmaple(X, y))))
```

Only the former makes sense to me, but given scikit-learn is scikit-learn and that it can't get "logistic regression" right, I have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment section answered it. It's doing the right thing by not applying the sampling to the test set.